# Define multiple contextPath routes for a ContextFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a Spring application with a ContextFactoryBean defined as such:

```
<bean id="adServerContext" class="com.intentmedia.springframework.jetty.ContextFactoryBean">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/initalpath"/>
    <property name="filterMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="/*">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="filter1"/>
                    <ref bean="filter2"/>
                </list>
            </entry>
            <entry key="/myServlet">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="filter1"/>
                    <ref bean="filter2"/>
                </list>
            </entry>
            ....
    </property>
    <property name="servletMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="/myServlet" value-ref="myServlet"/>
            ....
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So my servlet is at http://example.com/initialpath/myServlet. I'd like to define an synonym route so I can go to http://example.com/optionalpath/myServlet and refer to the same servlet. Can I define multiple paths without duplicating the entire context code block?

I'm using Spring 2.5.6.

Comment: that sure is an old version of Spring

Answer (score 0):

Servlet specification allows for such configuration:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()
>
> It is possible that a servlet container may match a context by more
>   than one context path. In such cases the
>   HttpServletRequest.getContextPath() will return the actual context
>   path used by the request and it may differ from the path returned by
>   this method. The context path returned by this method should be
>   considered as the prime or preferred context path of the application.

I am also pretty sure that Jetty will allow such configuration. So the question is whether your framework can support that... but I doubt that anyone here will know what the proprietary factory bean is doing.